# MySQL / SQL Can I return some non-table data under table headers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a procedure or function that can return all of my table headers with one row of data to act as application instructions underneath - these instructions will NOT be the same data types as the actual fields in the table.

E.g.

**MyTable:**

```
| pk | fName | lName | comment |
```

I'd run

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE PK = 0;`

This will return all of the headers (with no rows due to no PK with 0 existing) in to an ADODB.RecordSet where I can extract the field data type, character limit etc.

- I'd like to force return along with this, if possible, TEXT in each field so the output would include my **custom** identifiers for each type of column:

  ```
  | pk | fName | lName | comment |
    EX     UQ      UQ      OPT
  ```

So far all I've come up with is querying the database twice, one for the table and one for my custom entries which are only returned as a comma separated list E.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `definition` (tbl VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN

IF tbl = 'MyTable' THEN
    SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `pk` = 0;
ELSEIF tbl = 'MyTableId' THEN
    SELECT `id` FROM `tableId` WHERE `table` = tbl;
END IF;

END
```

This works but it's messy. I need a separate table just for ID's when really I'd like to keep the definitions in the stored procedure - something like this:

```
IF tbl = 'MyTable' THEN
    SELECT `pk`, `fName`, `lName`, `comment` FROM `MyTable` WHERE `pk` = 0
        VALUES 'EX', 'UQ', 'UQ', 'OPT';
```

Obviously that doesn't work and not even sure it's possible to do because the value `EX` isn't an `INT` like the `pk` column expects.

**Is this possible?!**

**EDIT**

I know I can do stuff like `SELECT 'Hey' FROM tbl;` but not sure of the link to include this under specific headers.

Comment: This should probably be handled in your presentation layer.

Comment: @Tim do you mean on the application side? This isn't such a good option for me because there will be different apps built - each time there's a change in tables it'd mean updating each of the apps, whereas I could just be altering the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting in my own answer just on the off-chance someone else comes looking for the same idea - I managed to sort of get it working in one query...

`SELECT *, 'EX,UQ,UQ,OPT' FROM MyTable WHERE PK = 0;`

On the app side all I have to do is get all my regular info from headers.count - 1 and then split() the last field name on the comma. I do a check also; if the split array.count isn't equal to the headers.count-1 then something is very wrong, just in case tables alter later on.

This means I can neaten my request for many table infos to one liners and have all that "custom" info in the stored proc on the same line. To extend I could actually specify the table headers in alignment instead of *:

```
SELECT
pk, fName, lName, comment,
'EX,UQ,UQ,OPT'
FROM MyTable WHERE PK = 0;
```